# Cannot enter BIOS after trying to fix bootloader after windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I have both installed windows 10 and ubuntu on my PC and usually I get the boot (grub?) menu when I start my computer. But after a windows 10 upgrade that menu is gone it just boots windows 10 directly. I have then googled on how to fix that problem and found:

[Fix a grub after windows update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084366/fix-a-grub-after-windows-update)

which suggests:

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

or

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

That did not fix the issue and further it has also removed my BIOS splash screen on startup showing the keys to press to enter BIOS etc.!

So:

1. How do I get my BIOS splash screen back again - and the ability to actually enter BIOS?
2. How do I fix/re-enable the multiboot menu so I can boot Ubuntu again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enter the BIOS/UEFI from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166120/how-do-i-enter-the-bios-uefi-from-ubuntu)

Comment: As I wrote I cannot even enter BIOS anymore after the computer starts and it also boots windows directly NOT ubuntu.

Comment: Don't split hairs. Follow the links and it works anyway. You don't need to be able to boot to either Ubuntu or Windows. To boot Ubuntu again follow the links to [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/).

Comment: Hm no idea why but now its back again. First I tried to hold down F2 based on the links you supplied but then it would not boot at all. Then I tried to hold down ESC instead and again it would not but. But when I then restarted with CTRL+ALT+DEL it was back (both the BIOS splash screen and the multi boot menu).

Comment: Now let's get started with getting Ubuntu back to booting again. I'm trying to build [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/) so any Q/A you upvote there would help a lot. I'm not trying to promote my own answer there either, but it would help that question if you upvote whatever answer works.